# Angular 12 - Bootstrap 5 multiple imported scss theme files load only one

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

I am using Angular 12 and Bootstrap 5.

I'm loading bootstrap from my scss file and I have 3 three theme scss files.

It looks like this:

style.scss:

```
@import './assets/styles/theme1.scss';
@import './assets/styles/theme2.scss';
@import './assets/styles/theme3.scss';
@import '~node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

The themes scss files look like this:

theme1.scss:

```
$theme: "darktheme" !default;

$white:    #fff !default;
$gray-100: #f8f9fa !default;
$gray-200: #ebebeb !default;
$gray-300: #dee2e6 !default;
$gray-400: #ced4da !default;
$gray-500: #adb5bd !default;
$gray-600: #888 !default;
$gray-700: #444 !default;
$gray-800: #303030 !default;
$gray-900: #222 !default;
$black:    #000 !default;

// etc...
```

From angular I want to be able to select the theme file I want to load.

At the moment it loads the first one and bootstrap.scss

I need it to load the selected theme file and bootstrap.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED ANSWER**

Here is an article to make
[Theming Angular with CSS Variables](https://medium.com/@amcdnl/theming-angular-with-css-variables-3c78a5b20b24)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: That's not the problem. The themes are working....I just need to be able to choose which one I want to use

Comment: Opps!!! ‍♂️ Sorry about that. It's my mistake.

Comment: I have edited the answer. If you can get an idea.